# mysql update increment int field that is null

Tags: mysql, null, increment

I have a very large table with two INT columns that are null on Default. This is a problem because since they are INT fields, it would help in many cases if they were originally set to 0.

So my questions are, is there a way I can UPDATE and INCREMENT(+1) these fields while they are like this (null on Default)? BTW.. I didn't have luck so far, it seems increment only works when the default=0

..or is my only option to Change the Default to none from null

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableName SET column = IFNULL(column, 0) + 1 WHERE ...
```

[More info on `IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).  It returns the first argument if it is not `NULL`, the second otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the field as `NOT NULL` to get away with the problem so that default value of 0 is used instead of null. The other option is to set column as zero whenever it is null.

```
UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = '0' WHERE FieldName IS NULL
```

Other alternative would be to issue [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to return 0 in case the column is null and then incrementing the column.

```
UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = IFNULL(FieldName,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard would be to use `COALESCE()`; this has been available in MySQL since version 3.23 (which was released into production in 2001):

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycolumn = COALESCE(mycolumn, 0) + 1
 WHERE my_other_columns = ...
```

I can't see any reason to choose `IFNULL()` over `COALESCE()` here.

Hope this helps.