# MySQL Update NULL Field with Field=Field+1 Strange Behavior

Tags: mysql

not sure if u face this strange behavior on MySQL table before: when the table field is default as `NULL`, I do a simple `UPDATE` statement run no problem. if I were to issue `field=field+1` then the value is not update. Then what i did is to insert `0` into the field and run the same `field=field+1` again then it works.

```
UPDATE table1 SET field=field+1 WHERE id=123;
```

is this expected behavior?

p/s: the `field` type is `double`

Comment: can you please share your query?

Comment: added SQL statement above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a null field then for update use.

```
//structure
UPDATE TableName SET column = IFNULL(column, 0) + 1 WHERE ...

//original
UPDATE table1 SET field = IFNULL(field, 0) + 1 WHERE id=123;
```

More details: [function_ifnull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Ref# [mysql-update-increment-int-field-that-is-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367212/mysql-update-increment-int-field-that-is-null)

Comment: my temporary solution is to change the field default value to zero (0), not sure this will works.

Comment: this will initialize the field to zero first and the increase it.

Comment: cool. that will work for me since i have some other fields like that and i don't wish to have so many IFNULL function check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because

```
NULL+1 = NULL
```

So you have to "trick" it to 0.

```
UPDATE table1 SET field=COALESCE(field,0)+1 WHERE id=123;
```